# Combine three foreach loops into one

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a problems with my report. In my database , I have columns and data like this

```
id = 1 , code = ' 123 ' , amount = ' 100 ' , type = ' - '

id = 2 , code = ' 123 ' , amount = ' 200 ' , type = ' + '

id = 3 , code = ' 456 ' , amount = ' 400 ' , type = ' - '

id = 4 , code = ' 456 ' , amount = ' 500 ' , type = ' + '
```

retrieve from the database is ok . I  have 2 objects to store. but problem I am facing right now is looping.

I want to show in my `blade.php` as a 1 record for same code like this.

I want my report format like this:

Record No = ' 1 '  Code = ' 123 ' From Amount = ' 100 ' To Amount = ' 200 '

Record No = ' 2 ' Code = ' 456 ' From Amount = ' 400 ' To Amount = ' 500 '

I have tried many ways. but actual outcome don't come out with my expected one.

```
$hello = Internal::where('t_code','LIKE','%-%')->where('transfer_type','=','-')->where('amount','>','5.00')->orderBy('id')->get();

$test = Internal::where('t_code','LIKE','%-%')->where('transfer_type','=','+')->orderBy('id')->get();

$aa = Internal::where('t_code','LIKE','%-%')->where('transfer_type','=','-')->where('amount','<=','5.00')->orderBy('id')->get();
```

I can retrieve the data from my database like this. But when i show this 3 object to my blade.php file will be the problem. How can i loop for my expected outcome.

at my Blade.php

Column Name : T Code

Column Name : From Amount

Column Name : To Amount

@foreach( $hello as $hellos )

td {{ $hellos }} td

@foreach( $test as $tests )

td {{ $tests }} /td

/tr
@endforeach

@endforeach

Comment: I wonder whether you are going about this the right way to achieve what you are looking to achieve. This seems to be some form of savings calculator or something of the sort, is this correct? Does type define whether to add to the previous entry with the same code number? Also, if you have 3 for loops, what do you intend to achieve?
Also, please show some code which you have tried, this can help us try to understand your intents better. Thanks.

Comment: $hello = Internal::where('t_code','LIKE','%-%')->where('transfer_type','=','-')

->where('amount','>','5.00')->orderBy('id')->get();

        $test = Internal::where('t_code','LIKE','%-%')->where('transfer_type','=','+')->orderBy('id')->get();

        $aa = Internal::where('t_code','LIKE','%-%')->where('transfer_type','=','-')->where('amount','<=','5.00')->orderBy('id')->get();

I can retrieve the data from my database like this. But when i show this 3 object to my blade.php file will be the problem. How can i loop for my expected outcome.

Comment: @MichaelThompson Sorry sir. I don't get it.

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw share your `foreach` loops code

Comment: @MehravishTemkar I already edit sir .

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw you can retrieve data with a single query and use one loop

Comment: @MehravishTemkar can u give example sir ?  how to do with single query ?

Comment: do you want the from amount to be minimum and to amount to be maximum amount for different `transfer_type`?

Comment: i just define from amount is if transfer_type == ' - ' 
and to amount is transfer_type == ' + '

Comment: @MehravishTemkar i just define from amount is if transfer_type == ' - ' and to amount is transfer_type == ' + '